# How to setup Email-to-Case to create a new Case with each user reply?

Tags: email, email2case, servicecloud

We have set up Email-to-Case for our org and we want to implement this requirement:

When a user sends an Email from the Case to a customer, the customer's reply should always create a new Case.

I know that is not optimal behavior, but it stemmed from the requirement to create new Cases when a new reply comes to a Closed Case. But now we want it for all of Cases.

I tried to remove the Thread Id from the emails by deselecting this 2 checkboxes but still the replies are tied to the existing Case. How can I implement this?

[image]

Comment: This is a very strange requirement. Trying to implement this in Salesforce will probably lead you down a road where you will be fighting against the natural behaviour of Salesforce Service Cloud. Maybe you could go back to the business team and discuss their process to understand what, in their business requirement, makes them want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

We eventually decided to create a trigger on the EmailMessage object, that checks if the Case is Closed. If it is, we clone it and create a new Case.